# My PAP2T adaptor times out, while softphone work fine on Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

How come my PAP2T cannot connect to my own Private Asterisk server? This set-up has worked fine for 18 months and I am not aware of any changes on the server. It could be a port being not properly forwarded, but it seems all ports are forwarded properly in the router configuration and the softphones work fine.

```
Display Name:           .............
User ID:                101
Hook State:             On
Registration State:     Can't connect to login server
Last Registration At:   0/0/0 00:00:00
Next Registration In:   14 s
Message Waiting:        No
Call Back Active:       No
```

When logged in into the asterisk server with asterisk -r, it only shows the registrations of the softphones, but not the pap2t adaptor.

Any advice, even on troubleshooting, is very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Increase the verbosity in logs and read through logs to see if it may indicate what the problem is when you try to connect the adapter.

   Here's how you increase verbosity:

   a) Edit **/etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf** using the editor of your choice

   b) Add the following line

   ```
   [options]
    verbose => 4
   ```
2. Via the CLI, you can also enable SIP debugging to view the SIP "conversation" that takes place between two devices (this makes for a fantastic tool when debuging all sorts of SIP issues)

   ```
   cli> sip set debug peer 101
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The PAP2T supports various timeout and retry counters.  You might want to experiment with what works well for you.  If traversing a NAT the address translation table may be forgetting about established connections if there is too great a period of inactivity.

If WAN management is enabled on your ATA, you should be able to remotely reboot the PAP2T in order to manually cause it to re-register with Asterisk. Direct your browser to http://[IP of PAP2T]/admin/reboot